# Getting Villages and other structures in Bukkit server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have replaced my Vanilla server with a Bukkit server and installed (only) 2 plugins: WorldEdit and WorldGuard.

Existing villages are still there, but new Villages are not generated.

I know this is the case because I used a village finder to find villages, and I know it works right because I tested it on Vanilla and it was tested out as accurate. But now when I use the village finder and visit the expected location of a previously unexplored village, the biome is right but the village is not created at all.

So, it seems that villages are either not created at all, or they are created in a different pattern. (same seed, but different server)

Temporarily, I added a 3rd [plugin, so that I can make NPC Villages on-demand](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/npc-village-creator/).

Can you suggest one of these solutions?

1. Replace my 3rd plugin with A full blown on-demand structures locator, including temples, abandoned mineshafts, witch huts, etc.
2. Get Bukkit to build the structures in the same locations as would be done by Vanilla server.
3. Get Bukkit to build structures at all to begin with, and then find a way to find them.

Here is `server.properties`

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Sun Apr 21 20:26:44 UTC 2013
generator-settings=
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=false
allow-flight=false
server-port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
spawn-npcs=true
white-list=false
spawn-animals=true
snooper-enabled=true
hardcore=false
texture-pack=
online-mode=true
pvp=true
difficulty=1
enable-command-block=true
gamemode=0
max-players=20
spawn-monsters=true
generate-structures=true
view-distance=10
spawn-protection=16
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? By "when going to a previously unvisited village location" do you mean when going to a set of co-ordinates where a village is expected but not present?

Comment: To my knowledge, Bukkit handles seeds in the same manner as a vanilla server. Please answer Schism's question, we aren't quite sure how you know where villages should be.

Comment: @Schism, I used a village locator AMIDST. I enter the seed, and it shows village and stronghold locations. I tested and got great success. Now, I have Bukkit server. My existing villages are still there and operate fine, HOWEVER, I went looking for a new larger village, and I entered a far away coordinate. I found the correct terrain, but no village. I know Bukkit was building from scratch because it took a long time to load. Perhaps I need to change a setting in `level.dat`?

Comment: What plugins do you have? It's probably one of them that's interfering with structure generation, so not knowing your plugins list means we can only guess. (We don't like being forced to guess, as you can see from the dearth of answers.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, WorldEdit and WorldGuard plugins That is all that there was at the time the problem was discovered, and there were no additional plugins in the past. I only installed [the village creator](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/npc-village-creator/) after the fact / it didn't cause the problem because I only installed it *after* discovering the problem. I have not installed any others besides these 3.

Comment: I've also used Amidst, and I can personally confirm that villages are where they should be. I use a number of plugins, including WorldEdit but not WorldGuard nor NPCv (though the latter doesn't seem to change natural generation, and I doubt the former will). Can you try seeing if villages will generate on a fresh server with bukkit but no plugins? Also, are you certain you have not changed the seed, which would change Amidst's predictions?

Comment: @Schism, I typed the seed into AMIDST based on the output of the `/seed` command. I guess I'll try removing WorldGuard and see if that helps, because I don't use it yet. If that does not work, I will try some of more drastic testing/fixing as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your config seems to be a little off.  Get the latest version of bukkit and then select the option for structures: true. That should fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a world in single player first, and then put in put it in the server world.

Comment: Actually it is a bit simpler. I could switch it to a Vanilla server, and I don't need to download it to single player that way. However, there is a problem with this answer. I would have to visit every village one at a time in order for those parts of the world to be generated. This is because every Minecraft world is endless, it cannot build the entire world at once, so it only builds the parts you visit. I am looking for a solution similar to the 1, 2 and 3 that I outlined above.